# Leaflet tracksymbol - how to calculate heading from bearing / location

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am currently trying to use the Leaflet.js Tracksymbol plugin - all works fine except that the directions of the markers are currently incorrect - Tracksymbol plugin requires a heading value, but i don't have a heading value available to me - only have bearing / lat / long / speed and course etc.

```
var trackSymbol = L.trackSymbol(myVal.latLng, {
                        course: myVal.course,
                        speed: myVal.speed,
                        heading: (Convert myVal.bearing somehow)
                    });
                    trackSymbol.addTo(targetLayer);
```

Can anyone advise how to either convert from the bearing to heading value, or calculate from what I have?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How is a bearing different from a heading? Degrees vs radians or something else?

Comment: According to the references:
Heading:
This is where my nose points - and seeing as my nose is attached to my head, this is where my head (and thus my machine) is pointing relative to North.
Bearing:
This is the angle between the location of an object, machine or destination and either:
- my heading. This is called 'Relative Bearing'.
- or magnetic north (direction toward the magnetic north pole). This is called 'Magnetic Bearing'.
[https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/8000/what-are-the-differences-between-bearing-vs-course-vs-direction-vs-heading-vs-tr]

Comment: OK. So what is your understanding of the difference in the context of your project? What is it that you already have that needs converting into the other thing and why?

Comment: I have a bearing value, but need to convert to heading - this is to ensure that the tracking symbol is displayed correctly and is facing the correct direction; currently it is not, but it is displayed at the correct geo location; just literally trying to get the icon to face the correct way!

Comment: I'm sure there are people who know more than me, but I'm intrigued. So the heading is the way the vessel is pointing, but the bearing is the way it's moving. They'd be the same if it was moving straight without influence of wind or sea?

Comment: Yes, i think so - but TBH that's why i was asking on here as like you say i am hoping that someone already has the answer to the way in which you can work it out from what i have already...